# Dynamic Content in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

This should be a quick one.

I'm pulling a list of id's and I need to place them in an array.

Here is my php code to get the list of id's

```
$get_archives = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM archive WHERE user = '$email'  ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_archives)) {
$insta_id = $row['insta_id'];

    $insta_id = "'" . $insta_id."',";

echo $insta_id;

    };
```

This echo's a list of id's that looks like this: '146176036','136514942',

Now I want to put that list into an array. So i tried something like this:

```
    $y = array($insta_id);
```

However that isn't working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myArray = array();

    $get_archives = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM archive WHERE user = '$email'  ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_archives)) {
    $insta_id = $row['insta_id'];

        $insta_id = "'" . $insta_id."',";


        $myArray[] =$insta_id;

        };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$y = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_archives)) {
  $y[] = $row['insta_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean like this: ?

```
$insta_id=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_archives)) {
$insta_id[] = $row['insta_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, and [push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) the values into it:

```
$values = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $get_archives ) ) {
  array_push( $values, $row['insta_id'] );
}
```